# Accessing SharePoint online data in SQL server using Odata feed

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql-server, odata

I tried accessing data from SharePoint's project web app using admin account(with full control) in excel using Odata feed. I was successful.

But when I tried to replicate the same thing with Sql server, I had this error: "Forbidden".

Any suggestion where I could possibly be going wrong.